# Whenever I press the FN key my keyboard thinks I'm trying to press F7

Tags: keyboard

I got this new keyboard that has the FN key, ever since I pressed it, it was always F7 and I had no clue why my FN key wasn't working, I get on a keyboard tester and sure enough, when I press FN its always F7, this hasn't been a problem in my life but now it's getting annoying. I haven't really done anything to make this happen and I don't know how to solve it either.

Comment: since *it was always F7* why do you say *I haven't really done anything to make this happen* ... since it never worked, you didn't break it, you bought it broken. Is it some cheap chinee no brand?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] and respond to the following: (1) What is the question? "Why?" is not equivalent to "how can I make it work as expected?". Don't let us guess what your question is, ask explicitly (2) Do F1, F2 etc. work by themselves? Or are they designed to require FN?